# Objective C, how to get M_PI (PI) value to 8 places (i.e. 3.14159265)?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Objective C, how to get M_PI (PI) value to 8 places (i.e. 3.14159265)?

```
double result = M_PI; // result value will be 3.14159
```

result need to be  3.14159265, why it does return few factions?

**NOTE:** When I'm assigning 3.14159265 to double result it loses last 3 factions I need to get those back and pass the result valuable.

Comment: Do you mean you want to display it somehow with only 8 decimal places?

Comment: M_PI is already to many more places than the 5 you show. Please note that the `%f` format specifier defaults to 5 decimal places. So if you simply logged the value, you will only see the 5 decimal places even though it is defined to a much higher precision.

Comment: Here's the line from `math.h`: `#define M_PI        3.14159265358979323846264338327950288`

Comment: `double result = 3.14159265;
NSLog(@"%.8f", result);`

Works just fine

Comment: @borrrden And so does `NSLog(@"%.8f", M_PI);`

Comment: Of course!! Even better!! @rmaddy

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wasn't so hard

```
double result = 3.14159265;
```

Comment: Need to get it programmaticaly, using the constant

Comment: @user2105542 That's no less programmatic than using a built-in constant `M_PI` :)

Comment: +1 best answer ever. It's not like the value of Pi ever changes.

Comment: When I'm assigning 3.14159265 to double result it loses last 3 factions I need to get those back and pass the result valuable. I think you didn't understand the question

Comment: This answer was funny but it's a shame it is getting all of these up votes because it actually makes no attempt to answer the question.

Comment: @rmaddy: This is [the bikeshed problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31253/).

Comment: @user2105542 The constant that comes built in with the Math framework is simply just a defined variables (just like the one above)... There will be no difference in accuracy using M_PI and just making your own constant that has pi listed out to say 16 or so places (whatever Math.h does).